# How can we stream videos to aws kinesis stream with flutter?

Tags: flutter, webrtc, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

So I want to stream videos to Kinesis stream from flutter. I have searched through the kinesis documents but couldn't find any SDKs available for flutter.

- Is there any library available to do it?
- Or if anyone has done it before, would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Never tried it, but I'd go with this approach: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html And you can use this to connect to API Gateway: https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

Answer (score 2):

As Far as I know, there is no current implementation in flutter for Kinesis Video "Producer" SDK.

However there's [Android Implementation](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/main/AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/demoapp), so what I would suggest is to add this Android Native Code in your project, and call it from Flutter Side.

The flutter [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) library can be modified to work with Kinesis Producer SDK.

Or like @Andrija said, REST API as a proxy for Kinesis can be used. But the downside is audio won't be streamed, you might need to container (MKV/MP4) the audio and video and send that.

Having said all that, if you can somehow encode the video and audio (MKV/MP4) from flutter, then you can use [`putRecord`](https://pub.dev/documentation/aws_kinesis_api/latest/kinesis-2013-12-02/Kinesis/putRecord.html) in [`aws_kinesis_api`](https://pub.dev/packages/aws_kinesis_api) flutter api to send it to Kinesis. But nowhere does it say it has to be video/audio, this is a generic api to put data into the stream.

EDIT: This confirms that as of current SDK, there is no Kinesis Producer code for Flutter https://github.com/agilord/aws_client/issues/242#issuecomment-860731956

Comment: Any update on this post ?

Comment: If you just want to stream camera to AWS and some server consuming it, it's better to go for Kinesis Video Stream Signaling channels, which are WebRTC based, and then you can use a webrtc library in flutter to connect to KVS.